# The grail of functional analysis?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis

> Does $g\in C([0,1],[0,1])=A$ exist such that $\{g^n ,n\in\mathbb N\}$ is dense in $A$ provided with the uniform norm?

with $g^2=g \circ g $

If we can find $g$ then $F$ a closed of $A$, $id \in F$ with $g\circ F\subset F$, we have $F=A$?

Comment: Which part of this is the question?  The existence of $g$?  The existence of $g$ and $F$?  The existence of $g$ such that every $F$ behaves as indicated?  You highlight one thing, but then appear to ask another question.

Comment: g is the grail, if it exists.

Comment: Right, but which part is the question?  You make an assertion about $F$, but follow it by a question mark.  Are you asserting that, if $g$ exists, then every such $F$ must be all of $A$, or are you asking whether that is the case (given the existence of $g$)?

Comment: "Does.......... .? "

Comment: Brouwer fixed point theorem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is no. If there was, then for some $N$ we would have $\|g^N\|\leq 1/2$, in order for $g^N$ to be within distance $1/2$ of the constant $0$ function. This means that the range of $g^N$ is contained in $[0,1/2]$. But then the same holds for $g^n$ for all $n\geq N$, since $g^n=g^N\circ g^{n-N}$. In particular $\{g^n\}$ cannot be dense in $A$.

Essentially the same argument shows that if some constant function is a limit point of the sequence $g^n$, then it is in fact the limit of this sequence.

Comment: Show the answer of @bathalf15320.

Comment: What do you mean? They have not posted an answer.

Comment: You answer is correct but I can t choose it, bathalf is the first.

Comment: With this in mind, I think the question that question, which could more appropriately be called the "grail in functional analysis", is whether the set $\mathrm{span} \{g^n ; n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is dense in $A$.

Comment: @Dattier If someone makes a comment but chooses not to post an answer, that should not prevent you from accepting someone else's answer.

Comment: I have choose the first answer, the answer of @bathalf15320, what's the problem with that?

Comment: @Dattier Accepting an answer means clicking on accept on an answer. You did not do that.